# how to close sweet alert by pressing esc key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert2

I am using sweet alert 2 and i have something like this.

[image: swal]

and here its implementation

```
$('#btn_undispense').click(function() {
        swal({
            title: "Are you want to unDispense this claim?",
            //text: 'you want to unDispense this claim ?',
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn-warning',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn-default',
            confirmButtonText: "UnDispense",
            cancelButtonText: "UnDispense & Delete",
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            closeOnCancel: true,
            allowEscapeKey: true,
            allowOutsideClick: true
        }, function(isConfirm) {
            var url = '@Url.Action("UnDispenseAndDelete", "ClaimData")';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                data: {
                    par:'@Model.ParKey',
                    par2: '@Model.ParKey2',
                    isUnDispensedOnly:isConfirm
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    debugger;
                    //1 undispensedOnly   //2 undispensed and delete
                    if (res === "1") {
                        showSuccessToast("Claim undispensed successfully");
                        if (@((int)Model.UserSession.UserRoleEnum) === 3) {

                            var url1 = "/Pharmacist/ClaimData/OpenClaim?par=" + '@Model.ParKey' + "&par2=" + '@Model.ParKey2' + "&par7=" + '@Model.ParKey7' + "&isClaimSearchPayer="+true ;
                            window.location.href = url1;
                        } else {
                            var url = "/Pharmacist/ClaimData/OpenClaim?par=" + '@Model.ParKey' + "&par2=" + '@Model.ParKey2' + "&par7=" + '@Model.ParKey7' + "";
                            window.location.href = url;
                        }
                    }else if(res === "2"){
                        var url1 = '@Url.Action("ClaimSearch", "Batch", new {area="Pharmacist"})';
                        window.location.href = url1;
                    }
                    else {
                        //  showErrorToast("Error");
                        showPopupModal("Errors", '@Url.Action("PopupError")');
                    }
                },
                failure: function () {
                    showErrorToast("Internal Server Error");
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

I want to close this sweet alert by pressing ESC key without excuting one of the two options so I added allowEscapeKey and allowOutsideClick options, the allowOutsideClick option is working correctly the problem is with the ESC key, whenever I press ESC it excutes the cancel button which is UnDispense & Delete and I just want to close the swal without excuting neither.

Comment: `SweetAlert2` will dismiss on `ESC` by default, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I believe it doesn't,,, I think it excutes the cancel button on ESC by default.

Comment: See this [page](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) Find `CTRL+F` => `A message with auto close timer` in this page, click on `try me` on opening the modal, try to fast press `ESC` and you'll see it close by `ESC`.. and there is no button to trigger. | OR you can try `Dynamic queue example`

Answer (score 0):

it may helps

```
  $('body').keypress(function(e){ 
  alert(e.which); 
  if(e.which == 27){
  swal.close();
   } 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 $(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 27) {
                swal.closeModal();
            }
        });
```